# 1980s/'90s sci-fi B-movie about a totalitarian future where a boy finds an abandoned combat robot

Tags: story-identification, movie, robots, dystopia

I once watched this movie on TV. It looks like it was released in the 1980s (or early 1990s).

The action takes place in a totalitarian future. At the beginning of the film, a boy hacker uses a computer. Then the police come and seemingly kidnap his parents.

He then finds an abandoned combat robot. If it is repaired, then it will be possible to organize a real resistance.

The action of the film developed very slowly. At this point, I seem to have turned off the TV.

And now I wanted to watch this movie.

It's non-animated.

Comment: How that combat robot looked like? Was it some sort of cyborg (may be even played by human actor) or some kind of machine? How that future looked like? Desert or high-tech?

Comment: Sounds a bit like Prototype https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Prototype_(1992_film)

Comment: The robot was like a machine inside which a person could be. Unfortunately, at this point I turned off the TV. It seems that the robot looked like a combat robot from the Mechwarrior computer games. In this sense, the film is more like Crash and Burn (1990).

The action took place in an ordinary modern city. However, its streets were completely controlled by the police.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Could be Robo Warriors (1996)
[IMDB](https://www.imdb.com/title/tt0117497/)

> The year is 2036 and Earth has been invaded: hope lies with the last
> Robo Warrior - a towering fighting machine.

Full movie:

Kid does some stuff on PC:
[image]

[image]

Alien "police" detects his actions:
[image]

Mecha:

[image]

Comment: That's it! Thanks a lot!

Comment: You're welcome =)